# Exclude directories from rewrite

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have  a directory favoris and when I access hostname.com/favoris its rewrite how I can prevent that?

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php [L]
```

file favoris/.htaccess

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "****"
AuthUserFile "/home/****/.htpasswds/public_html/favoris/passwd"
require valid-user
```

Comment: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` should already do that.

Comment: Do you have another htaccess in the directory that is overriding that, because @Sammitch is right what you have should already be doing that

Comment: I have htaccess file there but its auth only like
AuthType Basic
AuthName "UUU" ...

Comment: If accessing directory you need to add slash to end of path hostname.com/favoris becomes hostname.com/favoris/
You can force this with modrewrite if you want

Comment: adding slash did not help.

Comment: What exactly is it rewriting to? Is it getting routed to `index.php`?

Comment: Yes it's rewriting to index.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add Error document in sub folder .htaccess

```
ErrorDocument 401 "error place"
AuthType Basic
AuthName "****"
AuthUserFile "/home/****/.htpasswds/public_html/favoris/passwd"
require valid-user
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Due to the authentication there is a redirect to a page. If this page does not exist it will go to the "page not found" page.

Everything is explained here, how to create the 401 page and upload it. It solved the problem in my situation.

https://serverfault.com/questions/410445/excluding-a-directory-from-a-root-htaccess-rewrite-rule-to-allow-it-to-be-passw